# QQuickWidget makes frameless and transparent QMainWindow totally disappear

Tags: qt, qml

I want to embed a quickwidget into a window. But the window will become totally invisible if I add a quickwidget as its child. I'm using Qt5.4.0/5.4.2 + Windows10. Here is the snippets:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QQuickWidget>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    auto window = new QMainWindow;
    auto btn= new QPushButton("Can you see me?",window);    
    window->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint|Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
    window->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);

    //comment folloing code and everything will work fine.
    auto quick = new QQuickWidget(window);
    quick->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    quick->move(40,40);

    window->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Edit: I'm trying creating a `QQuickWidget` with no parent. And make it look like an embed widget.

```
auto quick = new QQuickWidget();
quick->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint|Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
quick->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
quick->setClearColor(Qt::transparent);
```

But, there is an severe problem. I can't click through its background although that is transparent. I have tested that the transparent background of `QWidget` can be clicked through.

Edit2: After I rebooted the computer, the quickwidget became invisible again.WTF

Edit3: Qt5.5.0 seems to be OK.

Comment: What does `main.qml` look like?

Comment: It's just a rectangle with fixed width, height and color specified.@Mitch

Comment: Looks like another bug in Qt, related to frameless windows. You may try do understand and debug the following source. It is a good start point: `src/plugins/platforms/windows/qwindowswindow.cpp`, method `QWindowsWindow::handleWindowStateChange`

Comment: There might be something wrong with `QQuickWidget`. I have my question updated. Do you have any idea? @SaZ